# Tool/gem to find commented code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Over the course of our project with multiple developers and styles, we have some tests and code  that are commented out. Is there an easy way to find all code that is commented out?

The tool should be smart enough to find out that it is ruby code that is being commented not, real comments.

At this point I can only think of grep like `grep #`, but it should be something smarter and less manual.

Comment: What differentiates "code" versus "comment text"?

Comment: I guess if it compiles its code otherwise its a comment :)

Answer (score 1):

This may be ugly but I think you can inspect each ".rb" file with a rake task, line per line, matching it with a regexp (something like /#.*\n/), and run an `eval("matching_string")` on each match. If the comment isn't ruby code it will simply fail.

Comment: Most (if not all) matched ruby lines will also fail.

Comment: True, but if the error raised is NoMethod maybe is possible to assume that the string is rb code. Just shooting a wild idea.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you'll need a `looks_like_ruby` method so you can do this:

```
puts line if line =~ /^\s+#/ && looks_like_ruby(line)
```

A quick and dirty implementation (off the top of my head)

```
def looks_like_ruby(text)
  text =~ Regexp.union((Kernel.methods + Object.methods).uniq.map(&:to_s))
end
```

Not perfect, but better than grepping for `#`